# Performance Improvement in finding intersection between two nested lists in Java 8

Tags: java, performance, list, java-8

This is a piece of code in Java 8 which finds the intersection between two different nested lists. When I execute this code, it causes a huge performance impact in my program. I am trying to figure out which part of the code causes this severe performance blow.

```
private static List<List<Integer>> findIntersection(List<List<Integer>> processlist1,List<List<Integer>> processlist2) {
        List<List<Integer>> intersect = processlist1.stream().flatMap(sl1 -> processlist2.stream().map(sl2 -> {
        List<Integer> lout = new ArrayList<>();
        lout.addAll(sl1);
        lout.retainAll(sl2);
        return lout;
    })).filter(l -> l.size() > 0).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define “intersection”? Actually, you are creating some kind of cross product between two outer lists.

Comment: What do you mean by "huge performance hit"? Using this on two List-of-Lists of size 3333 each does take a noticeable time, but I would not rate it the way you do. - Clearly, you are using a quadratic algorithm here, which you could avoid by using hashed set implementations.

Comment: It seems that your algorithm computes the set of all pairwise intersections of the (outer) Lists' elements. All pairs of lists with N and M elements is clearly O(N^2), so if you have "millions" you are in for a performance hit. - However: are the integers in any way limited in their range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid quadratic complexity of `retainAll` by converting one side of the cross product to a stream of `HashSet`:

```
List<List<Integer>> intersect = processList2.stream()
        .map(HashSet::new)
        .flatMap(set -> processList1.stream()
                .map(list -> list.stream()
                        .filter(set::contains)
                        .collect(toList())
                )
        )
        .filter(x -> !x.isEmpty())
        .distinct()
        .collect(toList());
```

Above assumes

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Comment: This does not compile: isEmpty, toList aren't known.

Comment: @laune It is customary to statically import collectors, such as `toList()`.  I neglected to mention that in the answer.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I appears that `map(HashSet::new)` transforms the List elements of processList2 from `List<Integer>` to `Set<Itneger>` which indeed improves to complexity of the intersection operations. What remains is the O(NxM) complexity required to pair all elements of the first list with all elements of the second list. M and N are in the order of "millions". We don't know how big the average length of the *inner* lists is and so it is difficult to assess the gain by converting these many lists to sets.

Comment: If lengths of the inner lists can be estimated as L, the improvement I propose takes it from O(NxMxL^2) to O(NxMxL).  Obviously, if L is small enough, it might not make a difference or even make matters worse, but that's something to be determined by testing with his actual inputs.   All else being equal, O(NxMxL) algorithm is at least worth considering over O(NxMxL^2).  Why do you believe that M and N are on the order of "millions"?  I don't see that anywhere in OP's question.

Comment: OP: "Code using HashSet classes really works faster even for a million records." as a comment to my (now deleted) answer where I was using a HashSet for one *outer* List. - Probably OP should have used `Set<Set<I>>` in the first place unless this causes excessive memory consumption.